# Render JSON with two objects in javax.json

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javax.json

Given these two annotated classes :

```
public class Clazz1 {
    @JsonbProperty("val11")
    String value11;
    @JsonbProperty("val12")
    String value12;
    .....
}


public class Clazz2 {
    @JsonbProperty("val21")
    String value21;
    @JsonbProperty("val22")
    String value22;
    .....
}
```

What I need is to generate a JSON that includes two objects, for example:

```
    Clazz1 c1 = new Clazz1();
    Clazz1 c2 = new Clazz2();
    c1.setValue1("ABC");
    ...  other settings

    JsonObject json = Json.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("c1", c1)
             .add("c2", c2)
             .build();
```

The `add` method above doesn't accept objects, how to create a JSON that includes both objects `c1` and `c2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the `JsonObjectBuilder` API and build the object manually:

```
JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory();
    JsonObject value = factory.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("c1", factory.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("value11", c1.getValue11()))
    .add("c2", factory.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("value21", c1.getValue21()))
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html

The other is to use the `JsonbBuilder` API:

```
JsonbConfig jsonbConfig = new JsonbConfig()
   .withPropertyNamingStrategy(
     PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_DASHES);
Map<String, Object> objectMap = new HashMap<>();
objectMap.put("c1", c1);
objectMap.put("c2", c2);
String json = JsonbBuilder.create(jsonbConfig).toJson(objectMap);
```

Refernce: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-javaee8-json-binding-3/index.html